# batch script to swap words / rename files

Tags: batch, batch-file, rename

could someone help me please?
I have win xp and bunch of e-books named like this:

**Title - Name Surname.mobi**
and I need a BAT file to get:
**Surname Name - Title.mobi**

I am almost able to swap what´s before and after the dash (except solving whitespaces yet). 
But I have no idea how to swap Name and Surname. I came this far, but it´s only the first swap. maybe some regular expression would be nice..  thank you, xcooba

echo off
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-." %%G IN ('dir /b') do ren "%%G-%%H.%%I" "%%H-%%G.%%I"
pause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly common for names to have more than two parts. Typically there is only one Surname, but the Surname may have an embedded hyphen. There may be 2 or more Names before the Surname.

It is also not unreasonable to expect that a Title may have a hyphen.

So your parser needs to be able to differentiate properly. Regular expressions would come in handy, but native Windows batch files do not have good support for regex.

A batch solution likely involves both a FOR loop and delayed expansion. But FOR variables are corrupted when expanded if they contain `!` when delayed expansion is enabled, and `!` may appear in the title. Delayed expansion can be toggled on and off as needed within the loop.

The following will properly handle a name like 
*"Some title! - 2nd part of title - Name1 Name2 Surname1-Surname2.mobi"*


and rename it to 
*Surname1-Surname2 Name1 Name2 - Some title! - 2nd part of title.mobi"*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "* - * *.mobi"') do (

  %== Change to root folder so path of current directory is empty ==%
  pushd \

  %== Separate fileName from extension ==%
  set "fileName=%%~nF"
  set "ext=%%~xF"

  %== Separate Title from full name. Assume everything before final " - " is Title ==%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!fileName: - =\!") do (
    endlocal
    set "name=%%~nxA"
    set "title=%%~pA"
  )

  %== Separate Surname from Name. Assume Surname is after final space ==%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!name: =\!") do (
    endlocal
    set "surname=%%~nxA"
    set "name=%%~pA"
  )

  %== Strip leading and trailing \ from name and title ==%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "name=!name:~1,-1!"
  set "title=!title:~1,-1!"

  %== Rename file, restoring spaces in Name and " - " in Title ==%
  ren "!fileName!!ext!" "!surname! !name:\= ! - !title:\= - !!ext!"
  endlocal

  popd
)
```

Life is so much easier with a decent regex tool. I have written [a hybrid JScrip/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that performs a regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. It is pure script that will run on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Using REPL.BAT, the solution becomes:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d "* - * *.mobi" ^| repl "(.*) - (.*) (.*)(\.mobi)$" "ren \q$&\q \q$3 $2 - $1$4\q" x'
) do %%A
```

Note that you cannot run either script more than once without corrupting the file names. It might be safer to move the files to a new location when you rename them. The MOVE command can rename and move in one step.

Comment: it´s working!! thank you very much for your fast answer. I am amazed. now I will spend time to study your script to learn more. thank you.. BTW why did you changed the root folder?

Comment: I use modifiers with FOR variable expansion to treat the name as a file path. The modifier extracts the title and name as a "path", but it will include the folder of the current directory in that "path". Changing to the root folder eliminates that problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy with it and it fully answers your question. (click on the check mark near upper left corner) That action lets others know it has been answered, awards you 5 rep points, and the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer can be accepted per question.